# Pass the JSON Observable outside of the function to be used again (Angular 5)

Tags: json, angular, rest

Was having an issue with trying to call upon the Observable in this function to loop in the component.html. When I try to loop it in the .html component files it shows up with nothing but the console log is actually showing that an observable is of the whole JSON data is being passed through to MonthlyCPMUList. What am I missing?

```js
    getMonthlyCPMU() {
    return this.http.get(this.CPMULink)
        .subscribe(MonthlyCPMUList => 
          console.log(MonthlyCPMUList),
            error => console.log('Error :: ' + error),
        );
  }
```

The Component.html file

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <th class="text-center">Month</th>
        <th class="text-center">CPMU</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-flow: column; align-items: center;">
      <tr *ngFor="let post of MonthlyCPMUList" class="row">
        <td class="text-center">{{post.Month | date}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{post.CPMU}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `MonthlyCPMUList` in your Observable subscription and your component are different here.

```
getMonthlyCPMU() {
    return this.http.get(this.CPMULink)
        .subscribe(MonthlyCPMUList => 
          console.log(MonthlyCPMUList),
            error => console.log('Error :: ' + error),
        );
  }
```

`MonthlyCPMUList` above is local to the subscription of your HTTP GET observable.

```
<tr *ngFor="let post of MonthlyCPMUList" class="row">
        <td class="text-center">{{post.Month | date}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{post.CPMU}}</td>
      </tr>
```

`MonthlyCPMUList` above refers to the variable in your component.

So for this to work, set your component variable to the value of your Observable's response like this.

```
return this.http.get(this.CPMULink)
        .subscribe(MonthlyCPMUList => { 
          console.log(MonthlyCPMUList);
          this.MonthlyCPMUList = MonthlyCPMUList;
         },
          error => console.log('Error :: ' + error),
        );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Nabin, that worked perfectly! I was trying to pass it from a service into the component html...which obviously was doing it wrong!